# Changing cursor for textfield() mouse over

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Can I change mouse cursor for textfield to appear as a clickable object?

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.utils.*;

import mx.core.*;
```

Comment: What do you mean? Usually you can use an `onEnter` event for a text-field for when a user clicks into it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the TextField inside a Sprite, sent the TextField's mouseEnabled to false, and the Sprite's buttonMode to true. For example:

```
var spr:Sprite = new Sprite();
var txt:TextField = new TextField();
txt.text = "Hello World!";
txt.mouseEnabled = false;
spr.buttonMode = true;
spr.addChild(txt);
addChild(spr);
```

Comment: sorry, still a problem, my whole APP is a sprite, now this sprite does not appear at all?

Comment: Must be some other bug in your code. Can't really give any advice without seeing the entire code in question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want the cursor to be a hand, which is a default for clickable objects. Try the following AS code:

```
myTextField.buttonMode = true;
myTextField.useHandCursor = true;
myTextField.mouseChildren = false;
```

Or, in MXML:

```
<mx:Text buttonMode="true" useHandCursor="true" mouseChildren="false" />
```

See [this article](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2008/03/27/flex-how-to-display-hand-cursor-on-components/) for an explanation.

**Edit**: This code uses the `mx.controls.Text` object. If you want it to work with `flash.text.TextField` objects, use [the solution provided by davr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545122/changing-cursor-for-textfield-mouse-over/2549630#2549630).

Comment: Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type flash.text:TextField.

Comment: What type of container do you use that contains the text field?

Comment: Riiight, you're using a `flash.text.TextField` object, instead a `mx.controls.Text`. That explains a lot. Those objects don't support these properties. Any chance you could use a `flash.text.TextField` instead?

Comment: is there another workaround such as making a invisible sprite around textfield?

Comment: If he's not using the Flex framework, I don't think he wants to import the framework just to get a hand cursor on a textfield.